# Moving the HelpLibrary to a different location

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have an SSD as system drive (C:) and it's a real lifesaver, however the free space is a premium value here, so I wish to keep non essential files away from this drive.
One of the major disk *'eater'* is the **VisualStudio HelpLibrary** used in Local Mode.
I have searched on the net, but with no luck, how to move this location (C:\programdata\Microsoft\HelpLibrary) to a different path on a normal hard drive (e.g. D:\HelpLibrary).
There is a way to do this with Visual Studio or we need to use some registry or config trick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the solution on this site.
http://mshcmigrate.helpmvp.com/news/moveorresetyourvs2010helplibrary

I write here the relevant part of that article.
However I suggest to read it because there are numerous information on HelpLibrary settings

1. Shutdown **"Help Library Agent"** tray application (of course, you can't change anything with this running)
2. Find the current path of the help library store looking at registry value **"LocalStore="** in HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Help\V1.0\
3. Go to that folder and Move everything to the desired location.
4. Update the registry value **"LocalStore="** in HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Help\V1.0\ with the new path.
5. Open the file **manifest\queryManifest.??.xml** in notepad and rename all occurrences of the old help path to the new path.

Tried and I was able to free up to 6GB of disk space on the SSD.

Answer (score 6):

The answer isn't really up to date anymore, at least not with my win8 VS2012 install.
you can find the key here
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Help\v2.0\Catalogs
and here
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Help\v2.0\Catalogs\VisualStudio11

I couldn't find the querymanifest xml, but I guess that isn't needed anymore. Since evrything is working peachy!

Comment: I can confirm this still works with Windows 10 and VS2013. I had to restart Visual Studio though.